# Saving time() IN Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using following code to save time. I have tried updating my column type to DATETIME and TIMESTAMP

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET update = :update WHERE id = :clientId');
                $statement->bindParam(':clientId', $clientId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam(':update', time(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->execute();


{"error":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update = '1367692928' WHERE id = 'I9pm90r-b4'' at line 1"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update` is a Reserved Keyword and happens to be the name of your column. In order to avoid syntax error, the column name should be escaped using backticks. Ex,

```
UPDATE users SET `update` = :update WHERE id = :clientId
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have the privilege to alter the table, change the column name that is not on the *Reserved Keyword List* to prevent the same error from getting back again on the future.